# Flutter: Fazer upload de imagem do usuário

Tags: flutter, dart

Olá, estou tentando enviar via API a imagem do usuário no momento do cadastro.
Preciso receber a imagem em base64 e receber o tipo do formato da imagem, exemplo ("image/png" ou "image/jpg").

Na minha estrutura eu consigo selecionar a imagem e armazena-lá em cache, mas não estou conseguindo capturar o tipo da imagem (png ou jpg).

Além disso eu estou recebendo a imagem desta forma:

> File: '/data/user/0/com.example.MyApp/cache/image_picker540161743069966467.jpg'

E preciso receber:

> image_picker540161743069966467.jpg

Minha estrutura de capturar a imagem selecionada do usuário:

Eu armazeno depois ela numa variável para enviar via POST:

```
List<int> retrato = userManager.retrato.readAsBytesSync();
'retrato': base64Encode(retrato),
'typeImage': '',
```

```
ImageSourceSheet({this.onImageSelected});

  final Function(File) onImageSelected;

  final ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      return BottomSheet(
          onClosing: () {},
          builder: (_) {
            return Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final PickedFile file =
                        await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                    onImageSelected(File(file.path));
                  },
                  child: const Text('Câmera'),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final PickedFile file =
                        await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                    onImageSelected(File(file.path));
                  },
                  child: const Text('Galeria'),
                ),
              ],
            );
          });
    } else {
      return CupertinoActionSheet(
        title: const Text('Selecionar imagem'),
        message: const Text('Escolha a origem da imagem'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            onPressed: () async {
              final PickedFile file =
                  await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
              onImageSelected(File(file.path));
            },
            child: const Text('Câmera'),
          ),
          CupertinoActionSheetAction(
            onPressed: () async {
              final PickedFile file =
                  await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
              onImageSelected(File(file.path));
            },
            child: const Text('Galeria'),
          ),
        ],
        cancelButton: CupertinoActionSheetAction(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          child: const Text('Cancelar'),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolver seus problemas você pode usar a biblioteca [path](https://pub.dev/packages/path). É só lembrar de importar no começo de seu arquivo:

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
```

> receber o tipo do formato da imagem, exemplo ("image/png" ou "image/jpg").

Existe a função [extension](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/extension.html) para isso:

```
String extensao = extension(file.path); // exemplo de resultado: ".jpg"
```

Vale deixar claro que essa extensão *incluirá* o ponto. Se você deseja retirar, é só remover o primeiro caracter:

```
print(extensao.substring(1)) // exemplo de resultado "jpg"
```

> E preciso receber: image_picker540161743069966467.jpg

Para isso você pode usar sua função [basename](https://pub.dev/documentation/path/latest/path/basename.html):

```
String NomeDoArquivo = basename(file.path); // exemplo de resultado: "imagem.jpg"
```

Comment: Muito obrigada, já estou conseguindo ter acesso ao que eu preciso. 
Porém estou com o erro "The method 'readAsBytesSync' isn't defined for the type 'String'." ao tentar converter a String do basename(file.path) em bytes para encondar em base64.

Comment: @JTeles Sugiro fazer outra pergunta em relação a isso, mas o que você deve "encodar" em base 64 não é o nome do arquivo, e sim o arquivo em si (seu conteúdo).  A função ```readAsBytesSync``` é uma função do "File" e não de uma String. Experimente ```readAsBytesSync(File(file.path))``` ou algo do tipo.